# Django instance return none from ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How could I solve this problem?
I want to create a model with an image and upload it to create a folder with the id of that object.

When I try to upload an image in the same class I can't reference the ***id*** to add in the url. The path looks like:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/foto_pacientes/None/image.png

pacientes.models.py

```
    class Pacientes(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        foto = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=foto_paciente)

    def foto_paciente(instance,filename):
        print(instance)
        return '/'.join(['foto_pacientes', str(instance.id.id), filename])
```

However, when I try to upload an image using a ForeginKey I can get the desired id. As:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/foto_pacientes/1/image.png

```
imagens.model.py

def imagens_historico(instance, filename):
    print(instance)
    return '/'.join(['historico', str(instance.id_historico.id_historico), filename])


class ImagensHistorico(models.Model):
    id_imagem_historico = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    imagem = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=imagens_historico)
    id_historico = models.ForeignKey(Historicos, related_name='imagens',
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: It is not possible if you are creating the instance for the first time, the instance will not have an `id` until it is saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot reference the id of the object which has not been created yet. What you can do is use the primary key of the object to create the folder to store the image .

Remove the field `id_imagem_historico = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`
If required , keep it .

This problem can easily be solved via this method . Put it in your models.py

The code :

```
def get_new_image_file_path(self , filename):
    return "imagens_historico/{}/image_name.png".format(self.pk)

class ImagensHistorico(models.Model):
    imagem = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=get_new_image_file_path)
    id_historico = models.ForeignKey(Historicos, related_name='imagens',
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
```

This will solve your problem and what you want is easily acheived.

Comment: The id and the primary key are one and the same... `pk` is just a convenient alias to the real field having the primary key (In this case `id`)

Comment: Yeah I know . But in your case , the object is not created and you will not get the id . But here you will get the id. and it will work. Try this on man first.